# Error: Invalid index to scalar value

Tags: python, scipy

Este es mi flujo de trabajo. Intento filtrar mis datos `y` y `z` para eliminar los valores nan. No logro corregir el error Invalid index.

```
data = logs[['DEPT','NPHI', 'RT' ]]
x = data ['DEPT']
y = data ['NPHI']
z = data['RT']

DEPT_inv = sp.sum(sp.isnan(x))
NPHI_inv = sp.sum(sp.isnan(y))
RT_inv = sp.sum(sp.isnan(z))

nan_array_DEPT = sp.isnan(x)
nan_array_NPHI = sp.isnan(y)
nan_array_RT = sp.isnan(z)

mask_NPHI = ~nan_array_NPHI
mask_RT = ~nan_array_RT
```

> ```
> NPHI_filtered = NPHI_inv[mask_NPHI]
> Error: Invalid index to scalar value
> ```

Comment: Falta algo de contexto.  `x`, `y` y `z` son arrays Numpy? ¿Cuantas dimensiones tienen? Si aportaras un ejemplo real de uno de ellos, por ejemplo de y seria más simple. Supongo que quieres el mismo array sin los elementos NaN. Si es esto último te estas complicando demasiado. Saludos.

Comment: Soy nueva en esto y desconosco las bases de Python. Asumo que son arreglos numpy. y y z son es una serie de mediciones puntuales correspondientes a un punto x. Es ahí donde se me dificulta el filtrado de datos, porque cada valor y, z debe corresponder con el mismo valor de x.

Comment: Haz `y = data ['NPHI']`, `print(type(y))` y  `print(y)` y agrega lo que obtengas a la pregunta a ver si aclaramos algo.

Comment: Esto es lo que obtengo                                                                      
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7       NaN
8       NaN
9       NaN
10      NaN
11      NaN
 ..
54706   NaN
54707   NaN
54708   NaN
54709   NaN
54710   NaN
54711   NaN
54712   NaN
54713   NaN
54714   NaN
54715   NaN
54716   NaN
Name: NPHI, dtype: float64

Comment: Te he dejado dos opciones, una usando Pandas, ya que por lo que comentas `data` es una estructura de datos de Pandas y la otra usando SciPy/NumPy con una máscara como intentas hacer tú. Ambas opciones retornan tres arrays con los valores no nulos correspondientes. Mira a ver si te sirve. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que parece `data` es un DataFrame de Pandas por lo que `x`, `y`, y `z` son columnas(`pandas.core.series.Series`). Supongo que al final pretendes obtener un array sin los valores `NaN`.

Ten en cuenta que:

```
DEPT_inv = sp.sum(sp.isnan(x))
```

Lo que nos da es un **entero con el número de elementos que son NaN** en la columna `x`. Posteriormente intentas aplicar la máscara a `DEPT_inv`, lo cual no es posible porque no es un array, es un entero (***"Invalid index to scalar value"***).

Para conseguir tres arrays con solo los valores no nulos puedes simplemente usar [`pandas.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```
import scipy as sp


DEPT_filtered = sp.array(data['DEPT'].dropna())
NPHI_filtered = sp.array(data['NPHI'].dropna())
RT_filtered   = sp.array(data['RT'].dropna())
```

Con esto consigues tres arrays con solo los valores no nulos de cada columna.

Si quieres usar una máscara de todas formas, entonces debes pasar cada Serie a un array de NumPy primero:

```
import scipy as sp

x = sp.array(data['DEPT'])
y = sp.array(data['NPHI'])
z = sp.array(data['RT'])


DEPT_filtered = x[~sp.isnan(x)]
NPHI_filtered = y[~sp.isnan(y)]
RT_filtered   = z[~sp.isnan(z)]
```

No especificas claramente cual debe ser el resultado final que quieres, ten en cuenta que si lo que deseas es elimir las filas de datos que tengan todos sus valores nulos entonces puedes aplicar `dropna` sobre datos directamente:

```
data.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace = True)
```